# Как получить список сохраненных сетей wi-fi с их паролями?

Tags: android, wifi, java

Как получить **список** сохраненных **сетей wi-fi** с их ***паролями***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да хранит пароли и еще как хранит.

Надо залезть в каталог: `/data/misc/wifi` и открыть файл: `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Это текстовый файл, и там будет список сетей с записями типа:

```
network={
  ssid="mywifi"
  psk="mypassword"
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  priority=9
}
```

Поле `psk` - хранит пароль "as-is".

Не уверен, что во всех версиях Android'а это так, но для JB это абсолютно точно (только что лично проверил для своего планшета).

P.S. Каталог и файл доступны только под рутом.

Comment: Мы говорим о возможностях библиотек самого андроида. Что пароли должны храниться понятно, но доступа к ним без рута не получить, что делает невозможным получить пароль для абсолютного большинства приложений.
P.S. недавно разрабатывал мобильный банкинг, там одним из требований заказчика была невозможность запуска на рутованых девайсах

Comment: @Lsoldier52:
1) ТС не ставил такого условия, что только средствами библиотек Андроида
2) Не понятно с чего это должны храниться пароли? Пароли как раз не должны храниться :) Это очевидный совершенно ляп разработчиков

Comment: Хм... вы хотите вводить пароль каждый раз при подключении к сети?

Comment: @Lsoldier52 не показывайте свою некомпетентность, существуют способы не хранить пароль и в то же время нормально работать без запроса пароля - погуглите :)

Comment: Что-то я ничего такого не нашел, жду пруфа

Comment: В Android 4.4.4 такого не увидел.

Comment: @avp ну значит исправили - и сделали как надо :)

Comment: А вот и не исправили. Отписаться просто не успел. 

Первый комментарий -- по результатам некорректного экперимента. Коллега пробовал прочесть на рутованном телефоне, но он не стал рутом.

После

     su
     cat /data/misk/...

все пароли проявились...

--

Вот это дыра, так дыра!

Answer (score 1):

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<WifiConfiguration> list = manager.getConfiguredNetworks();
```

Так вы получите список всех сетей. Получить пароли вы не сможете, андроид не позволяет этого из соображений безопасности

Comment: И слава богу, что не позволяет. (Разве что с рутом.)

Comment: А с рут правами как это делается?